# React-Native Android: Configuration with name 'default' not found with react-native-audio-toolkit Issue ( With Solution )

Tags: react-native

For those who's getting this error while build on android:

"Configuration with name 'default' not found"

for `react-native-audio-toolkit` as dependency which you can get [here](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
- Find android/settings.gradle and Change:

```
include ':react-native-audio-toolkit'
project(':react-native-audio-toolkit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-audio-toolkit/android')
```

to:

```
include ':react-native-audio-toolkit'
project(':react-native-audio-toolkit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-audio-toolkit/android/lib')
```

this should solve your problem